flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0 shoppify store share button not working on ANdroid only But working on iOS
I am using flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0 to display Shopify store inside web view. everything is working fine. But when I click on share button its not opening shareable apps bottom sheet, but its working fine on iOS devices.
InAppWebviewSetting:

And I have also added permission request:

Please see image attached.


androidOnPermissionRequest is deprecated

try using share_plus , Easy to use
Function crossed out , That is, it is no longer used or is about to be removed. Must be careful in use
